# loop create row inside list looping

Tags: java, excel, netbeans, apache-poi

I want to make an Excel worksheet like this:

```
NAME | ADDRESS | PH 
==================== 
Dad  |   IND   | 123 
Mom  |   IND   | 123 
Me   |   IND   | 123
```

`Dad`, `Mom` and `Me` are in the List. I've already tried to make the code, but it seems wrong. It doesn't write row by row, but instead overwrite everything in every loop. Here's the code:

```
HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook();
HSSFSheet sheet = wb.createSheet("new sheet");

Row row1 = sheet.createRow((short) 0);
row1.createCell(0).setCellValue("Name");
row1.createCell(1).setCellValue("Address");
row1.createCell(2).setCellValue("Ph");

List<pegawai> list_pegawai = test.list_pegawai();
int a = list_pegawai.size();
for (pegawai p : list_pegawai) {
    for (i = 1; i <= a; i++) {
         Row row2 = sheet.createRow((short) i);
         row2.createCell(0).setCellValue(p.getName());
         row2.createCell(1).setCellValue(p.getAddress());
         row2.createCell(2).setCellValue(p.getPh());
    }
}
FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\Documents\\workbook.xls");
wb.write(fileOut);
fileOut.close();
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "SUCCESS");
```

Thanks for your guys' answer and help :)

Comment: so whats the problem? what is test.list_pegawai();?

Comment: test.list_pegawai() use to call the query select from database.
the problem is my code run as many as the listsize and overwrite it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try

```
int i = 1;
for (pegawai p : list_pegawai) {
     Row row2 = sheet.createRow(i++);
     row2.createCell(0).setCellValue(p.getName());
     row2.createCell(1).setCellValue(p.getAddress());
     row2.createCell(2).setCellValue(p.getPh());
 }
```

you are already iterating through the list, no need to do twice. you do not want to create a new `row` everytime

Comment: oh, so we can use i++ on createrow. I think we must use ((short) 1) or ((short) variables)
 I got new lesson today. Thanks for helping!

Comment: I redefined `i` as a short, so no casting required.

Comment: Why are you using a `short` for the create row call? If you look at the [javadocs for Sheet.createRow](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Sheet.html#createRow%28int%29) you'll see it takes an int not a short...

Comment: @Gagravarr so I just use rownum? refer to your link.

Comment: @ScaryWombat How if I use int not short? could I?

Comment: @Gagravarr LOL, Sorry I did not check API.  As OP was originally casting an int to a short, I assumed (wrongly) that it took a short.  I have now updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try below line of code to make excel sheet from java.In between you can insert data from database by using any api to make database call.

```
HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Sample sheet");
Map<String, Object[]> data = new HashMap<String, Object[]>();
data.put("1", new Object[] {"Emp No.", "Name", "Salary"});
data.put("2", new Object[] {1d, "John", 1500000d});
data.put("3", new Object[] {2d, "Sam", 800000d});
data.put("4", new Object[] {3d, "Dean", 700000d});

Set<String> keyset = data.keySet();
short rownum = 0;
for (String key : keyset) {
    HSSFRow row = sheet.createRow(rownum++);
    Object [] objArr = data.get(key);
    int cellnum = 0;
    for (Object obj : objArr) {
        HSSFCell cell = row.createCell(cellnum++);
        if(obj instanceof Date) 
            cell.setCellValue((Date)obj);
        else if(obj instanceof Boolean)
            cell.setCellValue((Boolean)obj);
        else if(obj instanceof String)
            cell.setCellValue((String)obj);
        else if(obj instanceof Double)
            cell.setCellValue((Double)obj);
    }
}

try {
    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File("D:\\new.xls"));
    workbook.write(out);
    out.close();
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: why create a variable as a int then cast to a short?

Comment: Thanks for your code! But may I ask, what is keyset there?

Comment: It is just a Set of keys to get the data from data map (HashMap) we created earlier.Hence key set contains values 1,2,3,4 in this case that's it.